# Как правильно: "куры" или "курей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать: "Принимаем заказ на куры-гриль" или "принимаем заказ на курей-гриль"?

Comment: Правильно писать вопрос с большой буквы, а интересующее Вас предложение брать в кавычки.

Answer (score 7):

Правильно - **кур гриль**. Слово *гриль* здесь выступает в качестве неизменяемого определения, следующего за существительным (ср. масса нетто, вагон люкс, и т. п.).

Написание уже зафиксировано в [словаре](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EA%F3%F0%FB%E3%F0%E8%EB%FC&all=x)

Answer (score 4):

Все не так просто.

Если по словарю, то, конечно, "кур гриль".

А вот если  вдуматься... "Гриль", здесь, никак не сказывается на форме родительного (и других косвенных) падежа самого слова "куры", оно только несколько путает, мешая смотреть суть. А суть в том, что есть два конкурирующих варианта: "кур" и "куриц".

У слова "курица" две формы множественного числа - "куры" и "курицы"...
Как счетная форма все чаще используется "пять куриц" и проч. "Куры" таким образом с точки зрения грамматики становится аналогом собирательного "птица" (ср. "парное мясо" или "живая рыба").
Поэтому можно предвидеть постепенное закрепление де-факто существующего "куры гриль" (в родительном - "нет кур гриль") для названия самого кушанья, и "курицы гриль" ("куриц гриль") как форму для счетного и "разделенного" контекста: "пять мокрых куриц" выглядит вполне логично. Не "кур" же?!

> > — Пять куриц, — рассказывалось тут, — выщипали себе все перья, чтобы показать, кто из них больше исхудал от любви к петуху!

(C)http://andersen.com.ua/ru_istinnaya_pravda.html

И самое интересное. В случае приобретения словом куры исключительно собирательного значения сочетание "заказ на куры гриль" станет вполне возможным, ибо в таком случае слово может потерять одушевленность и тогда винительный падеж совпадет с именительным.

Еще смотрите здесь.
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/84836/

Что касается форм "курей" и подобных, то они не нормативны ни с каких точек зрения.

Да, забыл еще сказать, что против "куриц" будут активно возражать питерцы, в городском диалекте которых нет слова "курица", только "кура".